# Syntax shorthand for comparison operator in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have an if statement that wants to check:

```
if c=="a" or c=="e" or c=="i" or c=="o" or c=="w":
```

Is there a way to write this more efficiently so that I don't have to repeat c=="x" so much.
Something like `if c=="a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "w":`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
letters = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "w"]
if c in letters:
    foo
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `any()` and `all()` funcs. In your case

```py
if any(c==l for l in ['a','e','o','w']):
    # do stuff
```